# Elasticsearch takes time to index my data; can I do this async?

Tags: php, elasticsearch

Thanks to our using PHP instead of a modern web language we often hit the timeout limit when indexing a single item after a CRUD operation. This is because on top of the time it takes to save the data to MySQL it also has to wait for the Elasticsearch index to be updated as well.

The issue mainly lies in the fact that we use elasticsearch to index a *lot* of data, in order to lighten the load on MySQL, which can't represent the structure of the data it stores without a lot of processing (hierarchical data).

So, when we throw data at Elasticsearch after a CRUD operation, we throw a lot more than just the individual record that was updated; related records are also updated.

This takes time and PHP falls over because we can't fork in PHP. Our only option at this juncture seems to be to use something like beanstalk to index it "when we get around to it", but it seems to me like with a RESTful API like Elasticsearch has, we should be able to ask it to index some data, return a `201 Accepted`, and then ping our API back when it's done.

I can't see any way of doing this, nor even just to tell Elasticsearch to return immediately and let us assume it was OK.

Is a queue system my only recourse here? Ideas welcome.

Comment: No comments, no answers ater 10 hours, what a pity. Well, the situation you describe looks really miserable :-( Not the ElasticSearch expert, but more working with Solr, I nevertheless noted the UDB bulk update api of ElasticSearch[http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk-udp.html] and wonder if this might help.

Comment: What is your question exactly? Why does your PHP code have to wait for an answer?

Comment: @mconlin The problem is that PHP *does* wait for an answer. I want it not to.

Comment: maybe you should read up on how to make an [asynch POST in php](http://petewarden.com/2008/06/10/how-to-post-an-2/comment-page-1/)